# SPARQL query to remove "@en"

Tags: sparql

I have a large skos taxonomy that has some incorrect notation properties. Most of the properties are xsd:string but some appear with a "@en" language string. I want to modify the triples so as to remove the language string from these triples and convert them to xsd:string.

I tried the query below. It doesn't report any errors and commits successfully.

```
DELETE { ?s ?p ?o }
INSERT { ?s ?p ?o2 }
WHERE
{
  ?s skos:notation ?o .
  BIND(STRDT(STR(?o), xsd:string) AS ?o2)
}
```

However, the query does not result in any change to the triples data. Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Variable `?p` in your query appears to be unbound. Try:

```
DELETE { ?s skos:notation ?o }
INSERT { ?s skos:notation ?o2 }
WHERE
{
  ?s skos:notation ?o .
  BIND(STRDT(STR(?o), xsd:string) AS ?o2)
}
```

Comment: Ah, it didn't after all. The delete worked but the insert didn't. The query just stripped out all of the notations triples. I tried it again putting FILTER(lang(?o) = "en") in the WHERE clause; that resulted in the notations with "@en" being deleted but, again, no insertions.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT { ?s skos:notation REPLACE(?o2, "@en", "") }
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code solves the issue.